# popup modal appears but values didn't updated because server side click event didn't trigger

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, popupwindow

here is my code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnViewSalesOfficer"  CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-target="#ViewSalesOfficerModal" data-toggle="modal" runat="server" Text="View" OnClick="btnViewSalesOfficer_Click" />

<div class="modal modal-wide in" id="ViewSalesOfficerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="AVEModal" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div id="ViewModalContent">
                <section class="content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-info">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblHeadingSalesOfficerName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 " style="align-content:center">
                                            <img src="../../Img/avatar.png" class="img img-circle" style="width:150px;height:150px;">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class=" col-md-9 col-lg-9 ">
                                            <asp:Table ID="tbSaleOfficerInfo" CssClass="table table-user-information" runat="server">
                                                <asp:TableRow>
                                                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="bold">First Name</asp:TableCell>
                                                    <asp:TableCell ID="tbCFirstName"></asp:TableCell>
                                                </asp:TableRow>
                                                <asp:TableRow>
                                                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="bold">Last Name</asp:TableCell>
                                                    <asp:TableCell ID="tbCLastName"></asp:TableCell>
                                                </asp:TableRow>
                                                <asp:TableRow>
                                                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="bold">Username</asp:TableCell>
                                                    <asp:TableCell ID="tbCUsername"></asp:TableCell>
                                                </asp:TableRow>
                                                <asp:TableRow>
                                                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="bold">Gender</asp:TableCell>
                                                    <asp:TableCell ID="tbCGender"></asp:TableCell>
                                                </asp:TableRow>
                                                <asp:TableRow>
                                                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="bold">Date Of Birth</asp:TableCell>
                                                    <asp:TableCell ID="tbCDOB"></asp:TableCell>
                                                </asp:TableRow>
                                                <asp:TableRow>
                                                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="bold">Date Of Joining</asp:TableCell>
                                                    <asp:TableCell ID="tbCDOJ"></asp:TableCell>
                                                </asp:TableRow>
                                                <asp:TableRow>
                                                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="bold">Address</asp:TableCell>
                                                    <asp:TableCell ID="tbCAddress"></asp:TableCell>
                                                </asp:TableRow>
                                                <asp:TableRow>
                                                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="bold">Email</asp:TableCell>
                                                    <asp:TableCell ID="tbCEmail"></asp:TableCell>
                                                </asp:TableRow>
                                                <asp:TableRow>
                                                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="bold">Phone</asp:TableCell>
                                                    <asp:TableCell ID="tbCPhone"></asp:TableCell>
                                                </asp:TableRow>
                                                <asp:TableRow>
                                                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="bold">Qualification</asp:TableCell>
                                                    <asp:TableCell ID="tbCQualification"></asp:TableCell>
                                                </asp:TableRow>
                                                <asp:TableRow>
                                                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="bold">Designation</asp:TableCell>
                                                    <asp:TableCell ID="tbCDesignation"></asp:TableCell>
                                                </asp:TableRow>
                                                <asp:TableRow>
                                                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="bold">Salary</asp:TableCell>
                                                    <asp:TableCell ID="tbCSalary"></asp:TableCell>
                                                </asp:TableRow>
                                            </asp:Table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer text-right">
                                     <asp:Button ID="btnCloseModalPropView" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" runat="server" Text="Close" />
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Code Behind**

```
 protected void btnViewSalesOfficer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

         Button btn = (Button)sender;
         GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
         string SalesOfficerNo =row.Cells[0].Text;
         ViewSalesOfficerDetail(SalesOfficerNo);
        }

 private void ViewSalesOfficerDetail(string SalesOfficerNo)
        {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:2351/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Employee/" + SalesOfficerNo).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    List<SalesOfficer> SaleOfficer = (List<SalesOfficer>)javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(List<SalesOfficer>));
                    lblHeadingSalesOfficerName.Text= SaleOfficer[0].FirstName;
                    tbCFirstName.Text = SaleOfficer[0].FirstName;
                    tbCLastName.Text = SaleOfficer[0].LastName;
                    tbCDOJ.Text = SaleOfficer[0].DateOfJoining.ToString();
                    tbCDOB.Text = SaleOfficer[0].DOB.ToString();
                    tbCAddress.Text = SaleOfficer[0].Address;
                    tbCDesignation.Text = SaleOfficer[0].Position;
                    tbCEmail.Text = SaleOfficer[0].Email;
                    tbCGender.Text = SaleOfficer[0].Gender;
                    tbCPhone.Text = SaleOfficer[0].PhoneNumber;
                    tbCQualification.Text = SaleOfficer[0].Qualification;
                    tbCSalary.Text = SaleOfficer[0].Salary.ToString();
                    tbCUsername.Text = SaleOfficer[0].UserName;

                }
```

**Explanation**
above code works fine to trigger popup and it appears on the screen but the server side code didn't execute so values will no be retrieve and display in popup modal because onClick event didn't trigger on the other hand if onClick event triggers then popud didn't appears due to postback

Comment: Where is the javascript/event handler to handle it?

Comment: i'm haandling it from code behind on click event and scriptmanager is in master page

Comment: @SahilSharma i just added the click event code

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct way. You want to use jQuery.ajax({}); method to make an asynchronous call from UI to the server and handle the result.

Comment: i want use code behind method for asynchronous call